# TypeError: Cannot convert 0.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int64

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, typeerror, image-segmentation

I am trying to train segmentation model with gpu.

I set the pathes of train, trainmask, test and testmask images.
After I make each arraies, I try to train the model and get the following error:
`TypeError: Cannot convert 0.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int64`

I am able to train in another pc.

I tried tf.cast but it doesn't seem to help.

Here is the part of my code that cause problem:

```
EPOCHS = 500
VAL_SUBSPLITS = 1
#VALIDATION_STEPS = info.splits['test'].num_examples//BATCH_SIZE//VAL_SUBSPLITS
VALIDATION_STEPS = train_n_sample//BATCH_SIZE//VAL_SUBSPLITS
VALIDATION_STEPS = 10
#VALIDATAION_SPILIT=tf.cast(VALIDATAION_SPILIT, tf.int64)
model_history = model.fit(x=train_imgarray, y=trainmask_imgarray, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, epochs=EPOCHS,
                          steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH,
                          validation_split=VALIDATAION_SPILIT)
```